# Why does image literals not work in Xcode 11.2.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Why does it not work? I am on Xcode 11.2.1. I have tried restarting my Mac, but it still does not work.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you type Image Literal ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XsXByf7

Comment: Post your code in the question. Don’t use links and don’t use links to images of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It has of course nothing to do with image literals. Read the error message carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following

```
diceImageView1.image =
```

to

```
diceImageView1.imageView?.image = 'image literal'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write as follow:

```
diceImageView1.imageView?.image = // type Image literal
```

Or

```
diceImageView1.setImage(// type Image literal, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for

```
diceImageView1.image = UIImage(named: "DiceFive")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **#imageLiteral()** now